# Cannot figure out how to put a attribute to a click in Knockout.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

From what I understand this should be simple.
I am trying to make a row in a table clickable and to do that I wanted to use location.href on my tr.

My href is built with an Id I get from data-bind. How do I combine the click and attribute. I feel I am missing something evident here.

```
<tr data-bind="click : attr:{'location.href' : '/project/details/' + m.Id}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're conflating a couple of Knockout concepts here.

The `attr` binding is for binding HTML attributes for that element to the values on your model.

The `click` binding is a function that will be called on the click event (usually you'd reference a function on your view model but you can put an anonymous function inline).

To do what you want you should do:

```
<tr data-bind="click : gotoProject">
```

Then something like this on your view model:

```
this.gotoProject = function(){
    location.href = '/project/details' + this.Id;
}
```

Of course there's a million ways to hook up something like this and without seeing the code of your view model I can't give any more specifics.

Also relating to the `attr` binding so you can see how it is supposed to work. If you hadn't had it as the value of click but instead at the top level:

```
<tr data-bind="attr:{'location.href' : '/project/details/' + m.Id}">
```

This would result in the following (well it won't as it's not a valid attribute name but you get the point).

```
<tr location.href="/projecct/details/thisID">
```

Comment: No problem. Only thing I'll wanr you about is be careful with the `this`, it's messy in JS if you're not confident and doubly so in knockout due to how it binds. I'd strongly suggest using the `var self = this;` approach in your viewmodels for your sanity (mentioned here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html ).